# python3 file to array with quotes

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a data in the file something like the following:

```
[['1','1','abc'],['2','2','pqr'],['3','3','xyz']]
```

I am trying to load this data as it is in the list variable.

```
with open('abc.txt') as d:
    text = d.readlines()
```

I got the following output:

```
>>> text
["[['1','1','abc'],['2','2','pqr'],['3','3','xyz']]"]
```

Then I tried the command `text = d.read()` I got the following result:

```
"[['1','1','abc'],['2','2','pqr'],['3','3','xyz']]"
```

I am trying to achieve the output as:

```
>>> text
[['1','1','abc'],['2','2','pqr'],['3','3','xyz']]
```

Kindly, guide me to fulfill what I want to.

Comment: Ideally don't write lists to a plain text file in the first place, instead use something like `pickle`

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve desired output bywriting this code:

```
Import ast
with open('abc.txt') as f:
        ls = ast.literal_eval(f.read())
```

Welcome in advance.